# Navigation bar not working. Links and dropdowns not working

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I am learning how to build a website and I downloaded a template to help me get started. It is the urbanic free template.

I worked on the nav bar and I had the dropdowns working so moved on to other pages and elements. Now i tried testing the navbar again and the dropdowns wont work as well as the links i gave each menu item. Iv gone through the code but havnt been able to figure it out.

```
             <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
                                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="images/transparent logo.png" alt="Urbanic Template" title="Urbanic Template" /></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="ideces-nav-bar">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-top: 40px;">
                                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                                
                                <li class="dropdown"><a href="studyabroad.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">STUDY ABROAD<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="#">AUSTRALIA</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">CANADA</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">UK</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">USA</a>
                                        </li>
                                  </ul>
                              </li>

                                <li class="dropdown"><a href="testprep.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">TEST PREPERATION<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">IELTS</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">PTE</a></li>

                                  </ul>
                                </li>
                                
                                <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT US</a></li>
                                <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
                    </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
                </div><!--/.navbar -->
            </div> <!-- /container -->
        </div>
```

```
body, html { overflow-x:hidden; }

body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family:  'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetice Neue, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    
    font-weight: 300; 
    font-style: normal; 
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /* Fix for webkit rendering */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, span, p { font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetice Neue, sans-serif; }

* {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 !important;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 !important;
          border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.ideces_clear {
    clear: both;
}

.height30 {
    height: 30px;
}

.ideces-top-bar {
    min-height: 40px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
}

.ideces-top-menu {
    min-height:110px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    z-index: 5000;
    width:100%;
}

.ideces-top-menu .navbar-toggle {
    margin-top: 38px;
}

.ideces-top-menu .navbar-brand {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 30px 0 0;
}
```

What might i be doing wrong? I would hate to have to redo this and go through everything all over again. Thank you.

Comment: make sure bootstrap and jquery is structured correctly. crosscheck from the page that was working

Answer (score -1):

Seems to be working when you add jquery, bootstrap.js and bootstrap.css

```css
body,
html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetice Neue, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* Fix for webkit rendering */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
span,
p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetice Neue, sans-serif;
}

* {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 !important;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.ideces_clear {
  clear: both;
}

.height30 {
  height: 30px;
}

.ideces-top-bar {
  min-height: 40px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.ideces-top-menu {
  min-height: 110px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 5000;
  width: 100%;
}

.ideces-top-menu .navbar-toggle {
  margin-top: 38px;
}

.ideces-top-menu .navbar-brand {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 30px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="images/transparent logo.png" alt="Urbanic Template" title="Urbanic Template" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="ideces-nav-bar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-top: 40px;">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>

        <li class="dropdown"><a href="studyabroad.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">STUDY ABROAD<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">AUSTRALIA</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CANADA</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">UK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">USA</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown"><a href="testprep.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">TEST PREPERATION<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">IELTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PTE</a></li>

          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!--/.container-fluid -->
</div>
<!--/.navbar -->

<h1>content</h1>
<p>
Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. As explained in the [tour], this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers. Your answer is (included in)/(very similar to) [this answer](link/to/answer), and not very useful since it does not add any new value or information. Please avoid writing duplicate answers. Either edit your answer to add value or delete it altogether; this will ensure all questions and answers on the site remain useful and not scattered/duplicated.
</p>
<p>
Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. As explained in the [tour], this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers. Your answer is (included in)/(very similar to) [this answer](link/to/answer), and not very useful since it does not add any new value or information. Please avoid writing duplicate answers. Either edit your answer to add value or delete it altogether; this will ensure all questions and answers on the site remain useful and not scattered/duplicated.
</p>
```

Comment: If it is working for you then you should comment on it and flag for `Not reproducible or caused by typos` instead of answering.

Comment: I still cant get it to work. i have the following on top of index:
```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="js/colorbox/colorbox.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/ideces_style.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Been looking at my code and still cant figure it out. One thing i realized is i have 2 bootstrap.css files.  One bootstrap.css and the other bootstrap-3.4.1.css. Not sure if this has to do with why its not working? I am using dreamweaver and it created the files for me.

Comment: My site is at https://bluesugarbat.com/.

Comment: Try with the top 3 scripts on my example (jquery, bootstrap and bootstrap) and remove yours. Just for the check. Then decide what to do. Your bootstrap and jquery are old anyway.

Comment: Thanks but it still wont work. I removed the existing scripts and added yours and still nothing.